# How to transfer worlds from old broken tablets to new iPads

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I was younger I had a tablet and my brother and I were wondering if there was a way to transfer all our old beloved worlds from our old tablet to my new iPad.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SD card in the old tablet (as long as they are both the same brand), and the world's are saved on the card, then you should be able to put the card into the new tablet and download the worlds onto your new tablet. However, this can sometimes corrupt the worlds, so I recommend restarting it from the same seed instead of using the same world. However, either way, it will only work correctly of both games were the same update version, and restarting from the same seed only works if the original world was created in the most current update.